# Get total count of tests in NUnit3

Tags: nunit-3.0

I would like to get the total number of tests that NUnit3 is planning on running, for calculating progress, time remaining etc.

I would like to get this information from within a test, so that I can print information to the console about how many tests are remaining.

I have looked around the standard interface `NUnit.Framework.TestContext` but I can't spot anything that gives a list of the tests.

Some googling pointed me to the `NUnit.Engine` API but that seems to be for external use - every constructor wants the path to the test assembly and I can't even figure out how to get *that* information out of the `TestContext`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add some more details please on where/why you want to access this information? (Within a test? To print to console during the test run? In Visual Studio?) I ask, as there's no clear solution to this, but a few different possibilities - and knowing exactly what you want may help pin down the correct path to access this information.

Comment: Done - I want the information within a test.

Comment: Hiya, you can use `CountTestCases` from `Nunit.framework.api`. A nice reference to get some info on how to do it can be found here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-framework-driver/blob/5e1f9197afc9aaa3fe2984b890f6146b6b148638/src/nunit.v2.driver.tests/NUnit2FrameworkDriverTests.cs

Comment: Thanks @ShlomiBazel but I need this for NUnit 3 and that function no longer exists in the v3 framework. There's just a TestController and stuff which as I mentioned I could not get to instantiate. I'd like to avoid doing that anyway, since I'm already running the tests and loading them up externally just to count them seems a bit heavy handed. :-D

Comment: Have you tried using reflection to do that? Or that's a little bit too much ;p?

Comment: I'm definitely interested in trying that. Could you outline how that would work?

Comment: Using reflection you can get the total number of tests in the assembly, but this doesn't help... What if you apply filtering, and only run a number of tests, but not all. NUnit should provide this number somehow... I'm also interested in a solution to that :)

Comment: @oviuan I'm still not sure how you're even getting the test count via reflection. If you can outline that in an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Posted a sample, but I still don't think that's the right solution... I would still like to get from NUnit the number of tests scheduled to run, after filters and stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Using reflection to get total number of tests in a class

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit;

int GetTotalTestCount(Type testClassType)
{
    int result = 0;

    foreach (MethodBase method in testClassType.GetMethods())
    {
        if (method.GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>().Any())
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems a goot answer at the first read. But what happen if some filters are applied for the current execution ? I'm in the same spot tbh and still can't find any solution.
NUnit does not provide any information on the tests count or even the current filters applied (to count by ourself) it's a bit frustrating.